# Inject HTML code into a template in ksh.

Tags: html, shell, ksh

I have a template code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title> My page </title>
</head>
<body>
CODEWOULDCOMEHERE
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

And I have a shell script (ksh) that is suppose to generate some more code (to be placed in the `CODEWOULDCOMEHERE` palce).

I just don't know how to place that code there... I tried sed, but it didn't work... What's the most robust way to do that?

Worth to say that the code generated is quite long...

thanks!

**[EDIT]**

What I've tried so far:

```
HTMLCODE=$(genReportStatCellHtml)
HTMLOUT=$(cat report_template.html|sed -e "s/CODEWOULDCOMEHERE/\'$HTMLCODE\'/g")
```

which yields: `sed: 0602-404 Function s/GENERATEDHTMLCODE/\'a lot of html'/g cannot be parsed.`

And:

```
HTMLCODE=$(genReportStatCellHtml)
HTMLOUT=$(cat report_template.html)
    echo ${HTMLOUT/CODEWOULDCOMEHERE/$HTMLCODE}
```

which yields: `./test.sh[8]: ${HTMLOUT/CODEWOULDCOMEHERE/$HTMLCODE}: 0403-011 The specified substitution is not valid for this command.`

Comment: can you post what you have so far?  there are probably lots of ways to do the substitution, but how you generate the substituted value may lead to an answer that fits your usage best.

Comment: there ya go.. check out the edits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way of doing this is with here docs.  This is what that looks like when entered interactively:

```
$ cat <<EOF
> Some literal content
> You can do parameter expansion:
> $PWD
> as well as command expansion:
> `date`
> 
> EOF
Some literal content
You can do parameter expansion:
/tmp
as well as command expansion:
Fri Jul 29 13:36:10 CDT 2011
$
```

Or a shell script that does it

```
#! /bin/sh
cat <<EOF >output.txt
Some literal content
You can do parameter expansion:
$PWD
as well as command expansion:
`date`

EOF
```

Edit:  There's not really a good way to use an external template file with nothing more than the basic abilities of the shell, but it's pretty easy to do in other languages.  Here's a python one liner that'll do it.

We need to use a specific template key for the one-liner, so `CODEWOULDCOMEHERE` gets replaced by `{0}`.

```
$ cat report_template.html 
<html>
<head>
<title> My page </title>
</head>
<body>
{0}
</BODY>
</HTML>

$ echo "Heres the part that gets inserted" | python -c 'import sys; sys.stdout.write(file(sys.argv[1]).read().format(sys.stdin.read()))' report_template.html 
<html>
<head>
<title> My page </title>
</head>
<body>
Heres the part that gets inserted

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

All together, your script would look something like this

```
subst_template () {
    python -c 'import sys; sys.stdout.write(file(sys.argv[1]).read().format(sys.stdin.read()))' $1
}

genReportStatCellHtml | subst_template report_template.html > report.html
```

Comment: Hm.. could work, but what if I wanted to store the template in a separated file?

Comment: In that case, you might be best off doing this in another language;  There are many, fine template processors for practically any language (I'm rather fond of the jinja2 template engine for python).  You could still direct the substitution using a shell script, specify a template as a command line argument and pipe the substituted value in the standard input.

Comment: Well.. I ended up using the heredoc. what I did was instead of having the pure template I created a "htmlGenerator.sh" which is basically your script.. but at least the main script is not full of html.

Answer (score 0):

```
parse_file() 
{ # works just like HEREdoc
    eval echo  "\"$(cat $1 | sed 's+\"+\\"+g'   )\""
}

parse_file templatefile
```